# ExtensionDiscovery::scanDirectory() takes too long

Tags: files, performance

I have been debugging a bit an issue on our platform and I notice that our scanDirectory takes, from time to time, way to long, more than 100seconds.
I have been looking at the default.settings.php and I noticed

```
/**
 * The default list of directories that will be ignored by Drupal's file API.
 *
 * By default ignore node_modules and bower_components folders to avoid issues
 * with common frontend tools and recursive scanning of directories looking for
 * extensions.
 *
 * @see file_scan_directory()
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionDiscovery::scanDirectory()
 */
$settings['file_scan_ignore_directories'] = [
  'node_modules',
  'bower_components',
  'vendor',
];
```

I found that out that our sites/default directory is the one to blame.
Can I just add it here? Or should I include the subdirectories(fx sites/default/files)?

I am really surprised about this one. Been working with drupal years now and I see this first time!

Comment: It's very unlikely Drupal itself is causing this problem, rather the server. Maybe there are too many files directly in sites/default/files - some file systems struggle to stat files whens there are a lot of them in a single folder, especially in virtual/networked envionrments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the `file_scan_ignore_directories` setting changed, you should add the `$settings['file_scan_ignore_directories']` assignment in your `settings.php`, not `default.settings.php` lest it's overwritten when you update Drupal core.

Regarding what path strings to add to `$settings['file_scan_ignore_directories']`, that's up to you. As the comment block states, that setting affects all calls to [`ExtensionDiscovery::scanDirectory()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ExtensionDiscovery.php/function/ExtensionDiscovery%3A%3AscanDirectory/8.8.x) and [`FileSystem::scanDirectory()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3AscanDirectory/8.8.x) (if a `nomask` option isn't specified).

Add the most inclusive path that you know will never contain extensions or files to be scanned/discovered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's clear I need to edit stuff in settings.php. What is not clear is what is an extension. PHP extensions? At the moment underthe directory the cause problems I have my public files directory with all sorts of stuff -> pics, .csv stuff. Should I simply add  $settings['file_scan_ignore_directories'] = "sites/default/files" ?

Comment: Extensions are the term for any code package that extends Drupal functionality (i.e. modules, themes, install profiles, & theme engines). The class uses the scanDirectory method to look for .info.yml files to discover installable extensions.